# Несколько разных статичных сайтов в одной теме WP

Tags: wordpress

Создаю сайт на WP, где хочу разместить свои некоторые работы. Каждая работа состоит из одного или нескольких html-файлов, файла стилей, а также изображений и прочих ресурсов. Не могу понять как это всё поместить в файловой структуре темы WP.

Я хочу создать под каждую работу портфолио отдельную WP-страницу (или несколько, если работа - многостраничник). Подчеркну, что у каждой работы будут свои стили и ресурсы, то есть они не должны пересекаться или наследоваться от стилей темы WP.

В общем: **можно ли в одну тему WP поместить несколько других статичных сайтов?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никакого отношения к wp файлы html не имеют. Веб-сервер их отобразит самостоятельно. В какую папку положите, там и отобразит.

Создайте в корне сайта папку works, в ней подпапки, скажем, 1,2,3. В подпапке index.html и сопутствующие css и js.

По адресу http://site.org/works/1/index.html увидите работу #1.